# sql foreach without using cursor

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table "Student" in sql with a structure:

```
   StudentId   FirstName LastName

    1            X         Y

    ....
```

AND a table of Languages ,its structure:

```
  LanguageId   Name
    1          English
    2          Mandarin
    3          Spanish

   .....
```

and a relationship table StudentLanguage (languages spoken by a student)

```
  StudentId            LanguageId

    1                    1
    1                    3

    2                    1
    2                    2
```

from my asp.net page i want to filter students by spoken languages using checkboxes.

for example,when i check English,Madarin i want to have students speaking both English and Madarin
    When i check French,Spanish ,English ==>Get students speaking French,AND English,AND Spanish.

to do that i pass a table of Languages paramter called `@LanguageTable(LanguageId smallint)` to a stored procedure.
  how can i use this table to get the students  without using a cursor.

I have tried with CTE but no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select s.StudentId,s.FirstName,s.LastName
from Stundent s
join StudentLanguage sl on s.StudendID=sl.StudentId
join @LanguageTable on sl.LanguageId=@LanguageTable.LanguageId
group by s.StudentId,s.FirstName,s.LastName
having count(*)=(select count(*) from @LanguageTable)
```

Comment: +1, But you are missing the alias of the table for the SELECT on StudentId

Answer (score 1):

You need [relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

```
SELECT s.StudentId, s.FirstName, s.LastName
FROM   Student s
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                  FROM   @LanguageTable l
                  WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                                    FROM   StudentLanguage sl
                                    WHERE  sl.LanguageId = l.LanguageId
                                           AND sl.StudentId = s.StudentId))
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but:

```
SELECT s.StudentId, s.FirstName, s.LastName
FROM Student s
    INNER JOIN StudentLanguage sl ON sl.StudentId = s.StudentId
    INNER JOIN @Language l ON l.LanguageId = sl.LanguageId
GROUP BY s.StudentId, s.FirstName, s.LastName
HAVING Count(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Language)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff.Combining Group by join and the trick Count(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Language) gives the right result.